# Explicitly telling Ansible to use different set of credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, amazon-iam, credentials, profile

I am having an Ansible code which is running on an EC2 instance and deploys some AWS resources on the same account (let's call it account A). The EC2 instance where the Ansible code is running is having an EC2 IAM Role attached to it and Ansible is using that role to deploy other resources on the account.

Now, I need to deploy some other resources on another AWS account (call it account B) and I got the access key, secret and token for that account.

How to explicitly tell Ansible which is running on an instance in account A, to use those additional credentials which would then in turn deploy resources on account B?

Thanks,
Predrag

Comment: Well changing the IAM role applied to the instance is the correct way to do it. If you specify credentials as environmental variables, this should allow you to access account B even though the IAM role is for account A, although it is considered unsafe and not best practice.

Comment: Related to EC2 instances you can use this parameter [aws_access_key](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/amazon/aws/ec2_module.html#parameter-aws_access_key) and https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/amazon/aws/ec2_module.html#parameter-aws_secret_key

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to use [environment variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html). For example,

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxx AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=xxx AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=xxx ansible-playbook PLAYBOOK
```